# status: 415, error: 'Unsupported Media Type' post method

Tags: java, json, archivo

estoy terminando un trabajo donde tengo que hacer un metodo para que el usuario pueda subir su CV pero me aparece este error status: 415, error: 'Unsupported Media Type' post method, y message
:
"Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygubeq6ls3YIwSRA3;charset=UTF-8' is not supported."

la url que estoy utilizando para este metodo es esta:

```
let urlsolicitar = "http://localhost:8084/vacantes/solicitud/";
```

tengo esto en el java de eclipse el restController y el solicitudDto a archivo lo tengo como String, he probado a ponerlo como byte y sige con el mismo error

```
@PostMapping(value = "/solicitud/", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<?> nueva(@RequestBody SolicitudDto solicitudDto, @RequestParam("archivo") MultipartFile archivo) {
        solicitudDto.setFecha(new Date());
        Solicitud solicitud = new Solicitud();
        archivo.getContentType();
        solicitud = modelMapper.map(solicitudDto, Solicitud.class);
        solicitud.setUsuario(udao.findByUser(solicitudDto.getUsername()));
        if (srepo.save(solicitud) != null) {
            solicitudDto.setIdSolicitud(solicitud.getIdSolicitud());
            return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(solicitudDto);
        }else {
            String mensaje = "Alta NOOO realizada";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(mensaje);
        }
            
    }
```

y en el js tengo esto con el metodo post

```
function fSolicitar(idVacante) {
    document.getElementById("modal_solicitud").style.display = "none";

    let formData = new FormData();
    let archivoInput = document.querySelector('#archivo');
    let archivo = archivoInput.files[0]; 

     formData.append('archivo', archivo);
     formData.append('comentarios', document.querySelector('#Comentario').value);
     formData.append('estado', 0);
     formData.append('idVacante', idVacante);
     formData.append('username', sessionStorage.getItem("username"));

        fetch(urlsolicitar, {
            "method": 'POST',
            "body": formData
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(textoRes => {
            console.log(textoRes)
    
        });
}
```

el formulario

```
 <form id='form_publicar' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for='file'>Archivo</label>
    <input type='file' name='archivo' id='archivo' accept='.pdf'>
    <label for='Comentario'>Comentario</label>
    <input type='text' id='Comentario'>
    <input type='button' value='Solicitar' onclick='fSolicitar(${idVacante})'>;
</form>
```